# How to wait for each page before taking screenshot?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to have Selenium take a screenshot of the current page in the webdriver.  I'd also like to set the browser's dimensions before this occurs so that the screenshot can capture an image of a specific size.

I use this to change the window size:

```
webDrv.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(w, h);
```

And this to take the screenshot:

```
Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)webDrv).GetScreenshot();
ss.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(m_path, m_filename), ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

The problem is that on some pages, the screenshot will be taken before the browser has finished redrawing the page.

I cannot use the usual methods of checking (such as using JS to get the document.readyState) because the page is already loaded at this point, so any checks like this return true.

This is only a problem on pages that use Javascript to resize elements based on window size.  Pages that use CSS don't have this problem.

I can get around this by taking the entire HTML Body element before and comparing it to after the resize is completed:

```
webDrv.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(w, h);
int oldBodyHash = webDrv.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Text.GetHashCode(); //get a hash of the current html body
DateTime nextthink = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10); //hard time out incase there is no javascript resizing
while (webDrv.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Text.GetHashCode() == oldBodyHash && DateTime.Now < nextthink) //wait until hash changes or timeout occurs
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)webDrv).GetScreenshot();
ss.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(m_path, m_filename), ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

But then on pages using CSS to control changing elements, there is no change in the HTML Body.

It seems like it is one or the other, but it's not possible to cover for both possibilities?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't set the browser size at the start of the test? Is there a need to resize on the fly?

Comment: You are correct, that is definitely an option.  And for most cases it's fine, but there are sometimes instances where I'd want to resize the window multiple times for different size screenshots.

Comment: Why not just take the biggest screenshot you might need? Why would you need multiple different sized screenshots for the same error, etc?

Comment: I agree with JeffC, I can't think of a use case where simply setting a large screen size before your tests would not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that is totally true.  This looks like a problem that must be avoided by changing design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no actual solution to this other than changing the order in which we perform the operations; essentially the solution is to change the browser dimensions far enough ahead of time to ensure that JS resize activities complete before the screenshot is taken.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question question JeffC, but to directly fix you problem try adding a

```
browser.refresh()
```

in between the window resize and the screenshot-taking.

Comment: This would work on some occasions; simple web pages that don't require you to log in each time for example.  On other occasions, say where you had some text entered in a textbox control, refreshing the page would cause that information to be lost.  There are ways around that too, of course (eg: resizing before entering text).  My hope was to find a unified way that works on all occasions though.

Comment: So why don't you just resize and refresh before entering the information; as soon as the page loads?  That seems trivial to me.

Or, like JeffC says, Set in the beginning of the tests for the largest screenshot.

I guess my main question is, why would you need to resize to a smaller screen at any point?  Wouldn't sizing the window to the largest screenshot you need make it so that you capture all the information you needed from the smaller screen size?

Comment: Thanks, yes that works, it's only because that is the requirement I was given.